# Angular routes not working in refresh page in subdomain

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have an Angular Project. I builded and uploaded it to a `subdomain` of my server:

```
http://example.com/myapp/
```

but when I **refresh** the angular routes, It shows 404 error. for example when I refresh below url, it return 404!

```
http://example.com/myapp/dashboard
```

It normally (without refresh) work correctly.

I change `<base>` tag in index.html to `<base href="/">` or `<base href="/myapp/">` or `<base href="http://example.com/myapp/">` but it didn't work!

What I do?

I want this codes for subdomains (in apachi):
[angular.io/deployment](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#fallback-configuration-examples)

Comment: I want this codes for subdomains:
https://angular.io/guide/deployment#fallback-configuration-examples    in apachi.

Comment: In you manifest file set starturl to you app url

Comment: @TomaszVizaint Where is the manifest file?

Comment: in your linked article you have described everything about Fallback configuration

Answer (score 1):

you can use routerLink.

for example:

```
<base [routerLink]="['/myapp/dashboard']"></base>
```

for more details go to [here](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink#description)